# h:outputLink to external URL

Tags: jsf

I have the following code:

```
<p>
    <b>Website: </b>
    <h:outputLink value="#{HOTEL.hotel.website}" target="_blank">
        <h:outputText value="#{HOTEL.hotel.website}" />
    </h:outputLink>
</p>
```

I want to make just a simple link to an external URL that I hold in my DB. The problem is that it is taking correctly the URL but before the URL it puts the main URL of the website, see below:

```
http://localhost:8080/Hotels/faces/www.chernomorebg.com
```

In the database it is only

```
www.chernomorebg.com
```

I have tried with just a normal

```
<a href=""></a>
```

tag but again with no success. The I am using Tomcat 8 and PrimeFaces 5.1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You left off the leading `http://` in that url, so the browser assumes it's a relative url (a link to content elsewhere on the current site). Store the URL as `http://www.chernomorebg.com` in the database to solve this.

[This page](https://kb.iu.edu/d/abwp) has more information on this subject.